# iPad retina resources not displayed after ipa install

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5

I have a weird situation in testing retina resources for the New iPad. I have a project ready to be shipped which is supporting the New iPad. We have all of our retina resources in the project. When I do a build through Xcode onto a device that is physically connected to my machine the retina images display fine and all of the graphics look very crisp. However, when I do an archive to create an ipa file and install the app through the iphone configuration utility on the same device the retina images are not displayed, instead the regular sized images are displayed and it is quite noticeable.

Is this an issue with the iphone configuration utility or do I need so set some specific setting when archiving an IPA for retina resources to be included?

Cheers

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I have verified that my .ipa contains the @2x.png files and that my project is configured to use the 5.1 SDK and also have 5.1 as the deployment target. No retina images though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this happened because I was building on OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion. I switched our build server to 10.7.3 with the last official Xcode through the App Store and now things are fine.

I am not 100% sure that this was the actual reason, but ... good change it is :-)